# Reply to How's it going

Tags: word-usage, american-english, sentence-choice

When someone asks you on chat/face-to-face `Hey yourname, how's it going` 
what's the standard reply ? Is `Doing good` appropriate ? 
And should one ask back `How are you doing` ?
As these types of questions are not intended to have an answer but a normal way of 
greeting someone. It's probably common in US this way.

Comment: There is no "standard" reply... I noticed (some) people throw *how's it going*s around out of politeness, not really caring how people are doing (or not even expecting a response) . In reply, people throw back *well/good/great/fine*s instead of a more honest/open/elaborate update on their life/state/week/day. Try these: "Thanks, felling a bit under the weather today", "Oh, great, man, thanks, it's been a very productive morning"

Comment: You are not even really expected to give a meaningful answer; *how's it going* is more of a standardized greeting than a real question.  It's fine to respond with something like *Hi, yourname!*

Comment: How's it going.  What's up.  What's new.  What's shakin' bacon.  All are casual greetings that allow the answerer to respond as they see fit.  Possible responses are: Nothing much, you?  Things are going well, how about you?  Same old.  They found a heart, my transplant is tomorrow afternoon. It all depends on how you choose to answer.

Comment: @EllieK Thanks for the levity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most common reply is “Good, and you?”, the same as if someone asked how you are doing. (Some people prefer “well” over “good”, but that’s a hypercorrection.)

Note that this assumes the person is asking out of politeness rather than actual interest, so you are expected to give the standard polite answer in return.

With someone you know well, though, you are free to answer honestly if you’d prefer.

Answer (score 0):

"Doing good" is very informal AmE.

People do **talk** like that, though. That said, a more educated person says it tongue-in-cheek because standard answers are **I'm doing well** or **fine** or **great**.

Comment: Even the question `How is it going` is informal types right ? When you say `Doing good` is informal are you trying to say it's not the best kind of reply ?

Comment: @Amitwadhwa The question is generally: How's it going? with the contraction. No, informal means not formal. It depends on which level of language you want to use.